# create date formatted custom_meta field in wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a custom meta field to be used within a custom post type, that is to be the start time of a series of events.  However, I would like to run my query_posts off of this value, but it is not formatted in date/time format, therefore '1:00pm' shows up in the list before '9:00am'.  Is it possible to format this value in the db or at least prior to setting the 'meta_key' meta_value in my arguments for my query?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem a few times before. I'm going to use my most recent example because it sounds like it's along the same lines of what you're doing.

I had to create an event calendar using WordPress. In my custom post type, I had two fields: a start time and an end time. Instead of just using "1:00pm" as the start and end times, I also included the dates. This would allow for events that would last an entire weekend like a concert or a race.

What I'm getting at here, is once the user submitted that the event started on January 3, 2012 at 8:00 am and ended on January 3, 2012 at 10:00 am, I saved both of the variables using `strtotime()`. If you're not familiar with this function, you can read more about it here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php.

I also suggest using the datetime picker add-on for jQuery UI http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/.

I hope this helped. I know I was a little vague at times. If you need me to explain anything in more detail, don't be afraid to ask.